# How can i make my string search correct because it only shows the first hit?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, loops

Currently i have this code

```
for startLine, endLine in zip(list1, list2):
    print(startLine, endLine) 
    for line in lines[startLine:endLine]:
        if 'error ' in line and fail_lines:
                  line = line.rstrip()
                  search_results.append(line)
```

and the lists being referenced to are

```
list1 = [ '1' , '9',  '15']
list2 = [ '7' , '12',  '22']
```

For example on the code when the program runs

```
for line in lines[1:7]
```

The string search only gets the first hit of the "error" keyword even though I used the for loop function. How can I make it so that all the lines containing the error string inside the given range will be appended?

Comment: Could you just post the contents inside of `lines`?

Comment: line examples are
- error progress while looping
- connection time out error
- timed error sem
- in = error Time

Comment: Didn't you get this error ```TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method``` because you are not converting the `list1` and `list2` items to `int` values.

Comment: No its not showing that error, however when i try to output the search_results it only shows one "error" line from the text file

Comment: Is it possible you have an extra space in `if 'error ' in line:` , i.e. it should be `if 'error' in line:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this,

```py
lines = [
  "error progress while looping", 
  "connection time out error", 
  "timed error sem", 
  "in = error Time"
]

list1 = ['1', '9', '15']
list2 = ['7', '12', '22']
search_results = []

for s_line, e_line in zip(list1, list2):
  for line in lines[int(s_line):int(e_line)]:
    if line.find("error") >= 0:
      line = line.rstrip()
      search_results.append(line)
  print(search_results)
```

this gives me an output,

```sh
['connection time out error', 'timed error sem', 'in = error Time']
['connection time out error', 'timed error sem', 'in = error Time']
['connection time out error', 'timed error sem', 'in = error Time']
```

make sure to convert the extracted `s_line` `(start_line)` and `e_line` `(end_line)` to `int` before giving them as a **index** value.

Comment: Now these lines are in the output because the range are different in each case